# Add category using custom module

Tags: category

My code:

```
 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    $category->setName('check');
    $category->setUrlKey('new-category');
    $category->setIsActive(1);
    $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
    $category->setIsAnchor(1); //for active achor
    $category->setDisplayInMenu(0); 
    $category->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
    $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
    $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
    $category->save();
```

Now i dont want to show category in menu i m using `setDisplayInMenu` but its not working how can i do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to show category in menu than u have to use this

```
 $category->setIncludeInMenu(0);
```