# Create a category programatically in frontend don't work

Tags: category, frontend, programmatically

I have tried for hours to create programatically a new category under the root category.

My code so far:

```
$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->load(Mage::app()
        ->getStore()
        ->getRootCategoryId()
    );

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->setStoreId(1); 
$rootCategory['name'] = 'Bananaaa';
$rootCategory['path'] = $parentCategory->getPath();
$rootCategory['display_mode'] = "PRODUCTS";
$rootCategory['include_in_menu'] = 1;
$rootCategory['is_active'] = 1;
$rootCategory['is_anchor'] = 1;
$category->addData($rootCategory);
try {
    $category->save();
    echo $rootCategoryId = $category->getId();
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The result is:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`new_shop`.`catalog_category_flat_store_1`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_FLAT_STORE_1_ENTT_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`))
```

When I try to use "0" for I guess Admin-Store then the error message says that there is no table "catalog_category_flat_store".
No it isn't because there is only "catalog_category_flat_store_1" in the database.

I run this action from a controller and use the browser to start it.

Comment: See this question, as it may help - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78714/add-category-using-custom-module

Comment: Compare it with my code. It is already equal. And the result is that I have an integrity failure from mysql again.        It sounds like there is something missing because I have checked the way the backend save a new category but all over the Internet I can only find the same solutions. And I'm wondering why this works.

Comment: Is this function inside a frontend controller?

Comment: Yes, I use a frontend controller to run it. Is that wrong?